# Applying Theme to Telerik Report Viewer

Tags: telerik, reportviewer

I would like to apply the Expression Dark Theme to Telerik Report Viewer. I wasnt able to find a direct property called theme for Report Viewer. Could someone help me out as to how it is possible to apply a theme for this control?

Answer (score 0):

try out this.
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/reporting/telerik-reporting/theme-for-telerik-reporting.aspx

there is a solution you can download that shows you how.